# Flutter - Prevent looping pop

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter application, I have the two pages (`ViewPage` and `EditPage`) which both have buttons which directly route to each other. The `EditPage` page can be reached directly from the `HomePage` as well.

**Scenario Route:** `HomePage > ViewPage > EditPage > ViewPage > EditPage > ViewPage > ...`

With this example route, it requires user to pop several times to get back to `HomePage`. Is there a way to make the route from `EditPage` to `HomePage > ViewPage`, even if the user has gone back and forth several times between `EditPage` and `ViewPage`?

*Current Code:*

```dart
    Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => EditPage(
              contract: contract,
            ),
          ),
        );
```

I tried using various different navigation options without success (such as `pushAndRemoveUntil` below).

```dart
    var route = MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => EditPage(
          contract: contract,
        ),
      );

    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(route, (route) => !route.isActive);
```

***Clarification Edit:***

User's example route: `HomePage > ViewPage > EditPage > ViewPage > EditPage > ViewPage > EditPage`

Current route behavior when popping on last `EditPage`: `HomePage > ViewPage > EditPage > ViewPage > EditPage > ViewPage`

Desired route behavior when popping on last `EditPage`: `HomePage > ViewPage`

***Clarification Edit 2:***
Thinking about this more, here is the required logic to make this work (I think). When poping from `ViewPage`, always navigate to `HomePage` (I think I can make this work with a standard .push method).

However, when poping from `EditPage`, it needs to goto `ViewPage` (if navigated from `ViewPage` initially), or to `HomePage` (if was navigated to from `HomePage` initially). In summary, if `ViewPage` is in the route, go to the first instance of `ViewPage`, else navigate to first instance of `HomePage`.

I hope this all makes sense as it is a bit confusing to follow...

Comment: Hi, Ned! Just to clarify, how does this happen: Is there a link on the EditPage that the user can click that leads to the ViewPage?

Comment: Hi George, Yes, the `HomePage` and `ViewPage` have a link to the `EditPage`, and `EditPage` has a link to the `ViewPage`. All use `Navigator.push` to navigate to the pages.

Comment: What about `pushReplacement`?

Comment: The issue to me seems to be thhis: suppose the user is now on the second edit page, would he really wish to go back to the first ViewPage when poping? That being said, I still think this post is a good question that needs an answer.

Comment: @BenjaminS., When using `pushReplacement` for both the `HomePage > EditPage` and `EditPage > ViewPage` user routes, poping causes it to always go back to `HomePage`. With `pushReplacement` only on `EditPage > ViewPage`, popping causes `ViewPage` to show multiple times in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by using an if statement and an extra variable. If we navigate to Edit from the ViewPage, use `.pop()` back to the ViewPage, else (from the HomePage) '.push' the EditPage.

*ViewPage:*

```dart
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => EditPage(
      pushedFromViewPage: true,
    ),
  ),
);
```

*EditPage:*

```dart
if (widget.pushedFromViewPage) {
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
} else {
  Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => ViewPage(),
  );
  Navigator.of(context).push(route);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ned, wondering if you've tried [pushNamedAndRemoveUntil](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushNamedAndRemoveUntil.html) as shown below,

- main:

```
    void main(){
      runApp(new MaterialApp(
        home: new HomePage(),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
          'HomeScreen': (BuildContext context) => new HomePage(),
          'EditScreen': (BuildContext context) => new EditPage(),
        },
      ));
    }
```

- and then you can push it from EditPage (vice-versa) as,

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('HomeScreen', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
}
```

Comment: When using this, it navigates from `EditPage > ViewPage`, but I am no longer able to pop from `ViewPage > HomePage` and appears entire route is gone.

Comment: Yes, it will remove everything until your named route, above was just an example. In your case, you can define another route for ViewPage and in ViewPage call pushNamedAndRemoveUntil with HomePage or call it in HomePage with ViewPage. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I beleive I understand how this works, but I am failing to see how it would work in this scenario: `HomePage > ViewPage > EditPage > ViewPage > EditPage > ViewPage > EditPage`. What happens if I do a `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` from the last `EditPage` to the `ViewPage` in that scenario? Won't it just go to the last `ViewPage`, which then will then pop to the `EditPage`? I need it to go to the first `ViewPage` in the route, so that if a user pops from it, it goes to the `HomePage`.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. In that case, it'd go to the last ViewPage. Not sure why you're pushing ViewPage again from EditPage though, why not just pop EditPage after you're done editing. How is second ViewPage different from the first?

Comment: The `ViewPage` is always the same. There are multiple ways to get to the `EditPage` (from View and Home), but want to have a link from the `EditPage` to the `ViewPage` in case they came from the `HomePage`. Having this link allows the user to make this odd loop back and forth. It is a bit of an edge case for a user to do, but want to avoid the weird popping behavior if possible.

Comment: I see. Just thinking out loud here, why not just pop EditPage when you're done editing and then come back to ViewPage instead of creating a new instance? Similarly, when coming from HomePage, just pop EditPage when done.

Comment: Using `popUntil` would be more applicable to the situation I think.